# "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" trying to use pprint

Tags: python, json

I've tried this code to pretty print a `dict`:

```
import pprint

pprint({})
```

This throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 3, in <module>
    pprint({})
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Why is it not callable?

Comment: The error message says it: Because `pprint` is a module (not a function).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try importing using:

```
from pprint import pprint
```

The `pprint()` function is in the `pprint` module.

Comment: Thank you @JamieBull for your answer! For me, in Jupyter Lab, I need to write pprint.pprint() to make it  callable: 
 
    with open ("somefile.json","r") as src:
    f = json.load (src)
    pprint.pprint(f)

However, in Visual Studio Code, I only need to write pprint(f) . I do not completely understand why.